# Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST while transfer package

Tags: ajax, file-upload, multipartform-data

This is package form Client (browser):

```
...
Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebkitFormBoundaryxxx
...
```

This is package that is received from server:

```
...
Content-type: multipart/form-data
...
```

This is error log from server:

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

Can anyone help me how to fix this. Thank you!